# Python Scaling list elements to certain elements in another list

Tags: python, list

I have nearly 500 000 of the following kind of list mass generated in Python:

```
    example_list = [height, width, [characteristics]]
```

With height, width, and every characteristic being a whole, positive number.

The first step in finding a solution to my problem is comparing the list height and width. I succeed in this step if they are equal or have the same ratio. I can compare the ratios but I can't seem to scale the characteristics to that ratio.

For example this could be a possible solution:

```
    first_list = [8, 12, [1, 2, 3, 4]]
    second_list = [4, 6, [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Because the second list scaled gives:

```
    scaled_second_list = [8, 12, [10, 12, 14, 16]]
```

The second list now has the same heigt and width as the first and the characteristics are also scaled, so I can continue further comparison. I would like the scaled_second_list to continue. But I can't seem to scale the characteristics.

Thanks in advance!

For those interested; I'm trying to find 2 different perfect dissections of a rectangle.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you talk about scaling, at all.

Comment: I want scale every height and width in the second list to match those of the first list (if possible). In my example         scaled_second_list is    
     second_list scaled by a factor x2.

Comment: so you want all entries to have the same height/width, and scale their characteristics according to the transformation necessary to make it so?
What do you do in case height and width do not have the same ratio?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If they don't have the same ratio, I just have to know they don't. Thanks for answering!

Edit: Not ALL entries, just the 2 i'm comparing

Comment: @WouterVH Are `heigth` & `width` always integers? What Python version are you using? What do you mean *"I just have to konw they don't"*?

Comment: @Ev. Kounis I'm using SageMath which is based on Python but i don't know how I can give you the version but everything i've used in Python 3 works. If it's not possible to scale, to give a print "They don't scale" or something. Edit: And yes, these are always integers (positive, whole numbers).

Comment: where are these 500.000 lists contained? Do you have to check all against all or is there a **master** list against which all are checked?

Comment: @Ev. Kounis I generated them to be inside another list. I'm not an advanced programmer so i lost you at master list.

Comment: Tried `map` with applying own scaling function? I don't know what is your problem actually? You have already found out the factor but don't know how to scale the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already calculated the ratio, I think you are stuck at scaling up the characteristic sublist because its nested.
One solution could be this, I believe this is not the most optimized and elegant way of doing it, but it will work.

```
first_list = [8, 12, [1, 2, 3, 4]]
second_list = [4, 6, [5, 6, 7, 8]]
scaled_second_list = []

ratio = 3

for i in second_list:
    characteristic = []
    if isinstance(i, list):
        for j in i:
            characteristic.append(j*2)
        scaled_second_list.append(characteristic)
    else:
        scaled_second_list.append(i*2)

print scaled_second_list
```

I hope this helps!